# Cannot run pip from terminal on mac server

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip

I am running a mini mac server. It is running OSX 10.10.3 and I am running Python 2.7.9. I am trying to install some packages (namely selenium) using pip, but I cannot. If I type:

```
which pip
```

it does nothing. If I try to install pip,

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

I get:

Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages

I can see pip in the 2.7 site-packages but when I try something like:

sudo pip install -U selenium

I get -bash: pip: command not found

How can I remedy this?

Comment: yes. I tried entering that

Comment: Don't call `pip` directly, use `python -m pip` instead. This will always work if the called interpreter has `pip` installed.

Comment: @granger you can create a symlink to pip in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages from /bin/ and then avoid running it from `python` as @cel mentioned, though.

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: I used `python -m pip install -U selenium` and that did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The pip command is a very simple script. It is almost literally this:

```
#!<path to the python you are using>

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
sys.exit(main())
```

The almost is the first line, which should be a the path to the python you are using, that is the output of `which python`. I don't know why you don't have pip in your $PATH, but I see 2 ways to resolve this, either find the pip executable, and add it's location to your $PATH, or put the above script in one of the directories that is in your $PATH, and make it executable (`chmod u+x .../pip`)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether there is a pip-2.7 by explicitly running it at the prompt-

```
$ pip-2.7 -V
pip 1.5.6 from /path/to/python/packages/... (python 2.7)
```

If you get an affirmative response like this, perhaps then all you'd need is a symlink-

```
$ ln -s `which pip-2.7` ~/bin/pip
```

I'm suggesting that you put the pip symlink in your user's own ~/bin dir, but put it wherever most convenient to your purposes.

I've seen this situation with pip occur more than once on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Also, have you considered using a python distribution from homebrew? I have had a lot of problems with system-provided one.